# c# - WinForms MouseEnter this.label.BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, label, mouseenter

I want to change the `BackColor` of about 10 or more labels, but I do not want to write a new `private void label6_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)` function for each single label.

How do I address in one single function, the current label that the mouse enters uppon? Is this possible?

I thought something the lines of `this.label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);` but this does not address the label..

Comment: Create one event function, then perform an if statement inside to see if the sender matches one of the labels you want to adjust, then adjust.  Obviously point all your labels MouseEnter event to the one you create.  And thats all you gotta do

Comment: Thank you! A simple `if(sender.Equals(label6))` was all I needed. Again, thank you very much. Make sure to post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put few labels on a form and in the code behind write this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Color OriginalBackground;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var control in Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            control.MouseEnter += label_MouseEnter;
            control.MouseLeave += label_MouseLeave;
        }
    }

    private void label_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OriginalBackground = ((Label) sender).BackColor;
        ((Label) sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void label_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label) sender).BackColor = OriginalBackground;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.